# I'm trying to get the max games, wins and lost played for each team

Tags: python, pandas, csv, data-analysis

Here a sample of the CSV file I'm trying to edit as you can see L.A. Lakers appears twice in line one and again in line 15.
What I'm trying to do is the details of the team with the final amount of games, wins and lost each team had. G represents the games , W wins, and L lost in the csv file.
[image]

My imports

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
```

Reading and sorting the file

```
ranking = pd.read_csv("ranking.csv")
sortedranks = ranking.sort_values(["SEASON_ID"], ascending=False)
```

Getting the ranks for 2019 and removing duplicates but not working

```
rank19 = sortedranks[sortedranks.SEASON_ID == 22019]
rank19.drop_duplicates(subset="G", keep = False, inplace = True)
```

Comment: This data does not appear to be duplicated. You have two entries for the Lakers, but the total number of wins and losses is different in each row.

Comment: Oh then I would I be able to get the final record for each team as it's like that for the rest of the teams.

Comment: @JamesTollefson

Comment: Do you mean that you want to keep the record with a later ROAD_RECORD date? Or what do you mean by the final record? It is not clear from your description.

Comment: @kate-melnykova sorry about that I'm trying to get the final games, wins, and lose for each team

Comment: What do you mean by the term final? Is it later in the date (if yes, what column I should use to check it)?

Comment: @kate-melnykova the max games, wins, and lose each team had with season_id of 22019

Comment: It's getting even more confusing. I am not into sports scoring system. Maybe, you should add the explicit result that you want to get to your question. How would you aggregate LA Lakers, for example?

Comment: How do you propose to determine which one is the final record? The one with the later end date?

Comment: @kate-melnykova  ok let focus on one column I'm trying to get the max number of games played for each team. For example if the two names are the same but the games played is different. In that case I want to add the team with the max number of games played.

Comment: @JamesTollefson

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grouping your `DataFrame` can get the job done for you. I'll demonstrate using this simplified version of your data:

```py
import pandas as pd

data = {
        'Team':['L.A. Lakers', 'Denver', 
                'Houston', 'Utah', 'Oklahoma', 
                'L.A. Lakers', 'Dallas'],
        'G':[59,60,59,59,60,58,60],
        'W':[46,41,39,37,37,45,36],
        'L':[13,19,20,22,23,13,24],
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

Out:

```
          Team   G   W   L
0  L.A. Lakers  59  46  13
1       Denver  60  41  19
2      Houston  59  39  20
3         Utah  59  37  22
4     Oklahoma  60  37  23
5  L.A. Lakers  58  45  13
6       Dallas  60  36  24
```

Now I can use `groupby` and aggregate by max values:

```py
grouped = df.groupby('Team')[['G', 'W', 'L']].agg('max')
print(grouped)
```

Out:

```
              G   W   L
Team                   
Dallas       60  36  24
Denver       60  41  19
Houston      59  39  20
L.A. Lakers  59  46  13
Oklahoma     60  37  23
Utah         59  37  22
```